# How to convert/read word file using jquery/ajax

Tags: xml, jquery

I want to convert a word file into XML and read specific data using jquery/ajax.

below is my code:

```
function getFile(){   
   $.post("word.doc", function(data){
   $("#divFile").html("Data Loaded: " + data);
 });
```

with this function I am able to load the data but can't load it to XML file.

Please help.

Comment: .doc is a binary format that is not even close to trivial.  You can't use jQuery to convert it to XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The doc spec is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381461.aspx)  See the **Office File Formats** section (but @corbin is right -- its not close to trivial)